# saved photos from one drive onto my computer?

Tags: desktop-computer, onedrive, photos

I am trying to save photos from onedrive onto my pc and then delete them from one drive, however they also delete from the pc when doing so. How can I save them safely and then delete from one drive?

Answer (score 4):

OneDrive syncs your files in both directions, so that synced folder contents are identical on all devices. If you delete files on one device, they are supposed to disappear on the rest of them.

If you want to delete files off OneDrive, but keep them on one device, simply move them outside of the synchronized folder on that device.